# Armv8: request_irq but unexpected interrupt received

Tags: linux, interrupt

I want to register an IRQ handler in an arm64 linux kernel module, the kernel's version is 5.4.0, I use `request_irq` and it's okay to register. But when the IRQ happens, linux reports that `Unexpected interrupt received!`. So I don't know how to solve it.

I'm trying to use `request_irq` to register an IRQ handler in arm64 Linux ko:

```
    err = request_irq(40, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "hvisor", &hvisor_misc_dev);
```

And it's okey and has no errors. But when I inject IRQ `40` from el2 to el1, Linux reports a message saying :

```
[   87.294702] Unexpected interrupt received!
[   87.295733] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at drivers/irqchip/irq-gic-v3.c:650 gic_handle_irq+0x124/0x158
```

Why would this happen and how can I solve it? Who can help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. One must add a fake device in dtb like this:

```
    xxx {
        compatible = "xxx";
        interrupts = <0x00 0x?? 0x01>;
    };
```

where ?? is the irq number after substracted 32. Then in linux ko we must retrieve the irq number by using function `of_find_node_by_path` and `of_irq_get` like this:

```
    struct device_node *node = NULL;
    node = of_find_node_by_path("/xxx");
    int irq = of_irq_get(node, 0);
    request_irq(irq, ....);
```

Then everything is okey!